# How to use linux library functions in C user program?

Tags: c, linux, encoding

I am looking to use the init_bch , encode_bch and decode_bch that are available in the linux library

source code bch.c ( http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/bch.c)

Can I write my user program like

```
int main()
{
    ret = init_bch(args);
    return 0;
}
```

I think I need to somehow make a shared object and then link that while building my c source.

Side question: Does the bch.c source is already precompiled and linked into some shared object (perhaps libc.so or libm.so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is part of the kernel, and is not compiled into the kernel by default. (It is only used on certain embedded systems where BCH encoding/decoding are required to access raw NAND flash devices.) Even on those systems, it is not accessible from userspace.

If you need those functions in your program, you can copy the file into your own program and use it with some minor modifications. (Keep in mind that this will require you to license your program under GPLv2.)

Comment: hey thanks man. 
I got in touch with the guy who checked in the bch kernel lib.
He was kind enough to share his test suite with me.
Opensource guys are awesum :)